# I am running the Java program with "assert" on another thread and it is not showing AssertionError

Tags: java, multithreading, generics

I am experimenting with AssertionError. The first program which I wrote (only the definiton main method was present and also the toList()):

```
public class generic1{
    static List<Integer> ints;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ints = Lists.toList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3});
        assert inits.toString().equlas("[1, 2, 3,]");
    }
}
```

And I got the expected output, *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError*. When I modified the above code to extend the Thread class and run it on another thread, I am not getting the AssertionError as expected. Here is the code my attempt:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Lists {
    public static <T> List<T> toList(T[] arr) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for(T elt : arr) list.add(elt);
        return list;
    }
}

public class generic1 extends Thread{
    static List<Integer> ints;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        assert ints.toString().equals("[1, 2, 3,]");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ints = Lists.toList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3});
        Thread t = new Thread();
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Then I am compiling using:
**javac generic1.java**
and running using
**java -ea generic1**. But, I am not getting any output.

I am experiencing problem with the code. I will be glag if you kindly help me out. Thank you in advace.

Comment: Hint: this has nothing to do with assertions. Your `generic1.run()` code is never being executed. Look at how you're starting the thread...

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for pointing this out. I got the idea of where it went wrong.